# JS closure : undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        var waypoints = $('.box').waypoint(function (direction) {
            $(this).addClass('animated fadeInUp');

        }, {
            offset: 'bottom-in-view'
        });

        $('button').on('click', function () {
            waypoints.disable();

        });
```

When I click my button is says undefined is not a function? since I follow correctly how to use waypoints as in the documentation, so I bet it's closure issue.

Comment: My guess is that `this`, on line 2, is undefined or doesn't resolve to a DOM-element; thus giving an incorrect jQuery selector.

Comment: @Eric the first block work fine.

Comment: @lante jquery version 2.1

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are not using the jQuery version correctly.

```
waypoints.disable();
```

should probably be

```
waypoints.waypoint("disable");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not about the closure but about the global variable. When you use the waypoint, a global variable `waypoint` is registered so suppose the click callback should be as below without the 's'

```
 $('button').on('click', function () {
    waypoint.disable();
 });
```